# relational operator overloading not working in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators, structure

I am trying to implement Huffman encoding in C++ using custom made priority_queue. I am storing the information in structure named Node. Here is the code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
using ll = long long;
//two same name functions are for min heap and max heap(Function overloading)
struct Node{
    char letter;
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(char letter,int value, Node* left,Node* right){
        this->letter = letter;
        this->value = value;
        this->left = left;
        this->right = right;
    }

    bool operator < (const Node* &a){//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        if((this->value) < (a->value))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool operator > (const Node* &a){//HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        if((this->value) > (a->value))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Priority_Queue{

    public:
    int k;
    int sz;
    vector<T> v;

    Priority_Queue(int k){
        sz = 0;
        this->k = k;
    }

    void heapify(int index,int n){
        int max_index = index;
        for(int i = index*k+1;i <= min(n-1,index*k+k);++i){
            if(v[i] > v[max_index])
                max_index = i;
        }
        if(index != max_index){
            swap(v[max_index],v[index]);
            heapify(v,max_index,n);
        }
    }

    void heapify(vector<int> &v,int index,int n,bool trigger){
        //for calling min_heapify using function overloading
        int min_index = index;
        for(int i = index*k+1;i <= min(n-1,index*k+k);++i){
            if(v[i] < v[min_index])
                min_index = i;
        }
        if(index != min_index){
            swap(v[min_index],v[index]);
            heapify(v,min_index,n,trigger);
        }
    }   

    void Insert(T val){
        if(sz == (int)v.size()){
            v.push_back(val);
            ++sz;
        }
        else
            v[sz++] = val;
        int parent = (sz-1)/k;
        int node = sz-1;
        while(node >= 1){
            int parent = (node-1)/k;
            if(v[parent] < v[node]){
                swap(v[parent],v[node]);
                node = parent;
                parent = (parent-1)/k;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    void Insert(T val, bool trigger){
        if(sz == (int)v.size()){
            v.push_back(val);
            ++sz;
        }
        else
            v[sz++] = val;
        int parent = (sz-1)/k;
        int node = sz-1;
        while(node >= 1){
            int parent = (node-1)/k;
            if(v[parent] > v[node]){// IF CONDITION DOESN'T WORK
                swap(v[parent],v[node]);
                node = parent;
                parent = (parent-1)/k;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    void Pop(){
    if(sz == 0){
            cout << "Heap Underflow\n";
            return;
        }
        swap(v[0],v[sz-1]);
        --sz;
        heapify(0,sz);

    }

    void Pop(bool trigger){
        if(sz == 0){
            cout << "Heap Underflow\n";
            return;
        }
        swap(v[0],v[sz-1]);
        --sz;
        heapify(0,sz,trigger);
    }

    T Top(){
        return v[0];
    }

    void printHeap(){
        for(int i = 0; i < sz;++i){
            cout << v[i]->value << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    int n = s.length();
    vector<int> freq(26,0);
    for(int i = 0; i < n;++i){
        ++freq[s[i]-'a'];
    }
    Priority_Queue<Node*> pq(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 26;++i){
        if(freq[i] == 0)
            continue;
        pq.Insert(new Node(char(i+'a'),freq[i],NULL,NULL),true);
    }
    pq.printHeap();
}
```

I don't have much experience with C++ and I am having trouble overloading relational operators where I want to compare two structure pointers based on the value parameter.For example: if I enter `aab` , the if condition in Insert function should be executed but it never happens. I searched up a lot regarding overloading of relational operators but none of them seem to fix the issue I am facing. Can someone please help me ? What am I doing wrong while overloading the operator?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Your overloading is about comparing `Node` and `const Node*`. Your `Priority_Queue` should accept comparator like [`std::priority_queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).

Comment: Pointers are not objects, Node and const Node* are different things.

Comment: I am getting wrong answer. As I said, the if condition in the Insert function doesn't become true for the example I wrote . I am sure the operator overloading is at fault. Removing const keyword also doesn't help :(

Comment: I don't know how I would accept comparators .I searched up that too :(

Comment: You have written operators that compare `Node` to `Node*`. Your priority queue compares `Node*` to `Node*`.

Comment: So, I should write the overload function outside the structure?

Comment: @nmnsharma007 No, you cannot change the way C++ compares pointers. You have two choices, stop using pointers, or write your code to accept a custom comparator object.

Comment: No, you should overload for comparison between two `Node`s, and use a `Priority_Queue<Node>`.

Comment: Oh ! So, relational operators cannot be overloaded for pointers , right? And how can I pass a comparator to a function like STL priority queue does?

Comment: not sure if it will help, but here you can find a nice overview for operator overloading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @nmnsharma007 It's not possible to overload any operator for built in types (including pointers). You can't fundamentally change the language like that.

Comment: Ah ok. that makes sense . So it means, pointers have some default way of being compared right?

Comment: @nmnsharma007 Yes, essentially the addresses of the two pointers are compared. i.e. it is the pointers themselves that are being compared, not what they are pointing to.

Comment: Oh OK. Thanks . Apparently, overload didn't work at all and neither gave an error for comparing builtin types. Can u tell me how would I pass a comparator object to a function like STL priority queue does?Do I need to make an object or a just a comparator like I made above?

Comment: Your code was just using the default pointer comparison, which is why you got no error, but also it didn't work. It would take a little bit too long to explain how to pass a comparator like the STL. These objects are generally knowns as *functors*, maybe you could google that.

Comment: Yea sure, I heard about functors once but they looked scary. Maybe it's time to learn them finally. Thanks a lot for your help . I really appreciate it ^_^

Comment: @nmnsharma007 To be precise your overload was comparing a `Node` with a `Node*`. That is legal (but fairly useless), two pointers would have been illegal however.

Comment: So, a structure and a pointer can be compared ? On what basis? The address they hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should make your method look like this:

```
bool operator<(const Node &node) const {
   return value < node.value;
}
```

Notice the slightly different method signature. And then you should test it with an absolutely minimal method.

```
int main(int, char **) {
     Node first{'a', 10, nullptr, nullptr};
     Node second{'b', 5, nullptr, nullptr};

     cout << "first < second: " << (first < second) << endl;
     cout << "second < first: " << (second < first) << endl;
}
```

In your code, you might have to do this:

```
if (*v[index] < *v[otherIndex)
```

Another comment: don't name variables like `v`. That's going to bite you in the backside as your programs get bigger. Give them longer names that are more searchable and descriptive. `vec` is better than `v`.

Comment: OPs priority queue holds a vector of `Node*` not a vector of `Node`s

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'll modify the answer slightly.

Comment: Your overload method should be const.

Comment: why use abbreviations? How is `vec` better than `v`? I'd vote for `data`, at least make it a name, not the abbreviation of the actual name

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Vec is at least a LITTLE more searchable than v. And everyone has opinions on naming conventions. Note that I wouldn't necessarily use vec, either, but I was just trying to illustrate what I was trying to say.

Comment: hm ok. opinion based. But consider that `vec` isnt that searchable when the code uses `vector`s

Comment: I will improve my variable names . I agree with u on that :)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 It's still better than v. As we don't really know what the data really is, coming up with a better name is trick. Data isn't that great, either. nodeVector is probably better than any of the above.